# Isomorphic set to the rational numbers

Tags: set-theory

I'm looking for examples of isomorphic sets where the sets aren't finite to get a better understanding.
Is it correct to say that the rational numbers are isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/p \Bbb Z$? If not, could you explain why?

Comment: Not familiar with the $\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$ syntax.  Does it include $\frac{1}{6}$?  Personally, I would say that the rational numbers are isomorphic to $\{0\} \cup \{(a,b) ~: ~a \in \Bbb{Z_{\neq 0}}, ~b\in \Bbb{Z^+}, ~\text{gcd}(a,b) = 1\}.$

Comment: What kind of isomorphism are you considering?

Comment: If you're only interested in the ordering, you may be interested in [Cantor's isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_isomorphism_theorem)

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Do you just mean as ordered sets?  Do you mean as an additive group?  As a field?  The set theory tag suggests you mean as ordered sets, but that really needs to be explicit in your question.

Comment: Do you understand what $\Bbb Z / p\Bbb Z$ means? And what an isomorphism is? Your question suggests you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume you're talking about group isomorphisms here (although there are other contexts where the concept of isomorphism makes sense). A group isomorphism $\varphi:G\to H$ needs to satisfy two conditions:

1. $\varphi$ should be a *homomorphism*: that is, $\varphi(x\cdot y)=\varphi(x)\cdot\varphi(y)$ for each $x,y\in G$;
2. $\varphi$ should be a *bijection*.

The group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ (in one of its constructions) consists of the equivalence classes of integers modulo $n$, with the group operation being addition modulo $n$. In particular, the cardinality of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is exactly $n$ - if you divide an integer by $n$, there are only $n$ possibilities for the remainder: $0,1,\ldots,n-1$. On the other hand, the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ (as an additive group) are infinite. Therefore there can't be any bijection between $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$, since bijections preserve cardinality. This rules out the possibility of a group isomorphism $\varphi:\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Q}$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ - property 2 automatically fails. (The case where $n=p$ for $p$ a prime is a special case of this.)